# How many HTML elements can "modern" browsers "handle" at once?

Tags: html, json, performance, dom

*"modern" because that definition may change over time (and specifically I mean desktop browsers)*

*"handle" because that may vary depending on machine configurations/memory, but specifically I mean a general use case.*

---

This question came to mind over a particular problem I'm trying to solve involving large datasets.

Essentially, whenever a change is made to a particular dataset I get the full dataset back and I have to render this data in the browser.

So for example, over a websocket I get a push event that tells me a dataset has changes, and then I have to render this dataset in HTML by grabbing an existing DOM element, duplicating it, populating the elements with data from this set using classnames or other element identifiers, and then add it back to the DOM.

Keep in mind that any object (JSON) in this dataset may have as many as 1000+ child objects, and there may be as many as 10,000+ parent objects, so as you can see there may be an instance where the returned dataset is upwards towards 1,000,000 => 10,000,000 data points or more.

Now the fun part comes when I have to render this stuff. For each data point there may be 3 or 4 tags used to render and style the data, and there may be event listeners for any of these tags (maybe on the parent container to lighten things up using delegation).

To sum it all up, there can be a lot of incoming information that needs to be rendered and I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle this scenario.

Ideally, you'd just want to render the changes for that single data point that has changes rather than re-rendering the whole set, but this may not be an option due to how the backend was designed.

*My main concern here is to understand the limitations of the browser/DOM and looking at this problem through the lense of the frontend. There are some changes that should happen on the backend for sure (data design, caching, pagination), but that isnt the focus here.*

**This isn't a *typical* use case for HTML/DOM, as I know there are limitations, but what exactly are they? Are we still capped out at about 3000-4000 elements?**

---

I've got a number of [related](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/web-browser-chrome-25-firefox-19,3459.html) [subquestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery) for this that I'm [actively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656837/how-many-element-ids-can-browsers-safely-handle-before-performance-degredation) [looking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923524/how-many-divs-can-you-have-before-the-dom-slows-and-becomes-unstable?lq=1) [up](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/dom-html5-css3-performance/) but I thought it'd be nice to share some thoughts with the rest of the stackoverflow community and try to pool some information together about this issue.

**What is "reasonable" amount of DOM elements that a modern browser can handle before it starts becoming slow/non-responsive?**

**How can I benchmark the number of DOM elements a browser can handle?**

**What are some [strategies](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/) for handling large datasets that need to be rendered (besides pagination)?**

**Are templating frameworks like mustache and handlebars more performant for rendering html from data/json (on the frontend) than using jQuery or Regular Expressions?**

Comment: There are "modern" browsers in big fat desktop machines and "modern" browsers in cheap smartphones. Client system capacity is going to be your limiting factor.

Comment: @Pointy exactly my point, thats why I put it in quotes, but I should be clear this is for desktop browsers

Comment: If the datasets are upwards to 10,000,000 points, you should rethink the concept and only output small parts of it at a time, as no user would want to wade through 10 million elements on the same page, or so I would think at least ?

Comment: Well there are desktop machines with 1GB of memory and desktop machines with 16GB.  What's your actual user audience like? Do you have any control over it?  Are you sure you can just dismiss tablet/phone users, who represent more and more overall Internet traffic all the time?

Comment: In addition, the aspect of the DOM is to allow for the same elements to be re-used, take HTML5 Canvas for example. The DOM should remain dynamic and "objects" should remain in a data store until required. You will more likely be limited by bad code and memory leaks before reaching some sort of crucial mass of element in the browser.

Comment: @adeneo I do acknowledge that there is a problem with the way the data was designed but this isnt the issue per se. There are a lot of backend strategies for this but I want to focus on frontend solutions/limitations.

Comment: @Pointy I'm more so focused on trying to understand the limitations of the frontend/client with the DOM, not really trying to solve the problem here, it's just to illustrate.

Comment: I know you specifically ruled out pagination, but I feel compelled to point out that this pattern is pretty well traveled. Having said that,  and acknowledging that any answers will be speculative/fuzzy, my experience has been that most desktop browsers start to act sluggish/suspicious when the list/report/shopping cart/etc has maybe 10-20k html elements, (and then comes pagination). Obviously more memory and CPU will yield better mileage, but scales in the millions seem clearly impractical.

Comment: **Use canvas custom rendering if you need billions of elements.** Canvas is the only way because "modern" browsers are shitty.

Comment: Rendering will be a problem ( slow ) but getting that chunk of data to your browser without delays is another challenge. I would reconsider my design.

Comment: My strategy is using virtual scrolling to avoid rendering out of view data, and canvas for in view data if this is still too heavy. This way my pages remain very responsive even on IE11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a question for which only a statistically savvy answer could be accurate and comprehensive.

**Why**

The appropriate equation is this, where N is the number of nodes, bytes<sub>N</sub> is the total bytes required to represent them in the DOM, the node index range is `n ∈ [0, N)`, bytesOverhead is the amount of memory used for a node with absolute minimum attribute configuration and no innerHTML, and bytesContent is the amount of memory used to fill such a minimal node.

> bytes<sub>N</sub> = ∑<sup>N</sup> (bytesContent<sub>n</sub> + bytesOverhead<sub>n</sub>)

The value requested in the question is the maximum value of N in the worst case handheld device, operating system, browser, and operating conditions.  Solving for N for each permutation is not trivial.  The equation above reveals three dependencies, each of which could drastically alter the answer.

**Dependencies**

1. The average size of a node is dependent on the average number of bytes used in each to hold the content, such as UTF-8 text, attribute names and values, or cached information.
2. The average overhead of a DOM object is dependent on the HTTP user agent that manages the DOM representation of each document.  W3C's [Document Object Model FAQ](https://www.w3.org/DOM/faq.html) states, "While all DOM implementations should be interoperable, they may vary considerably in code size, **memory demand**, and performance of individual operations."
3. The memory available to use for DOM representations is dependent upon the browser used by default (which can vary depending on what browser handheld device vendors or users prefer), user override of the default browser, the operating system version, the memory capacity of the handheld device, common background tasks, and other memory consumption.

**The Rigorous Solution**

One could run tests to determine (1) and (2) for each of the common http user agents used on handheld devices. The distribution of user agents for any given site can be obtained by configuring the logging mechanism of the web server to place the HTTP_USER_AGENT if it isn't there by default and then stripping all but that field in the log and counting the instances of each value.

The number of bytes per character would need to be tested for both attributes values and UTF-8 inner text (or whatever the encoding) to get a clear pair of factors for calculating (1).

The memory available would need to be tested too under a variety of common conditions, which would be a major research project by itself.

The particular value of N chosen would have to be ZERO to handle the actual worst case, so one would chose a certain percentage of typical cases of content, node structures, and run time conditions.  For instance, one may take a sample of cases using some form of randomized *in situ* (within normal environmental conditions) study and find N that satisfies 95% of those cases.

Perhaps a set of cases could be tested in the above ways and the results placed in a table. Such would represent a direct answer to your question.

I'm guessing it would take an well educated mobile software engineer with flare for mathematics, especially statistics, five full time weeks to get reasonable results.

**A More Practical Estimation**

One could guess the worst case scenario.  With a few full days of research and a few proof-of-concept apps, this proposal could be refined.  Absent of the time to do that, here's a good first guess.

Consider a cell phone that permits 1 Gbyte for DOM because normal operating conditions use 3 Gbytes out of the 4 GBytes for the above mentioned purposes.  One might assume the average consumption of memory for a node to be as follows, to get a ballpark figure.

- 2 bytes per character for 40 characters of inner text per node
- 2 bytes per character for 4 attribute values of 10 characters each
- 1 byte per character for 4 attribute names of 4 characters each
- 160 bytes for the C/C++ node overhead in the less efficient cases

In this case N<sub>worst_case</sub>, the worst case max nodes,

```
= 1,024 X 1,024 X 1,024
  / (2 X 40  +  2 X 4 X 10  +  1 X 4 X 4  +  160)

= 3,195,660 . 190,476.
```

I would not, however, build a document in a browser with three million DOM nodes if it could be at all avoided.  Consider employing the more common practice below.

**Common Practice**

The best solution is to stay far below what N<sub>worst_case</sub> might be and simply reduce the total number of nodes to the degree possible using standard HTTP design techniques.

- Reduce the size and complexity of that which is displayed on any given page, which also improves visual and conceptual clarity.
- Request minimal amounts of data from the server, deferring content that is not yet visible using windowing techniques or balancing response time with memory consumption in well-planned ways.
- Use asynchronous calls to assist with the above minimalism.

Comment: Your 160 byte C++ overhead seem to be a   false estimation. The numbers above suggest more a 10-30kb per element that is used in the C++.  I'm a busy experienced C++ programmer and i'm scared about the complicity of the DOM nodes, but even i would have underestimated it by 50%.

Answer (score 10):

Your answer is: 1 OR millions. I'm going to copy/paste an answer from a similar question on SO.

> To be honest, if you really need an absolute answer to this question, then you might want to reconsider your design.
>
> No answer given here will be right, as it depends upon many factors that are specific to your application. E.g. heavy vs. little
>   CSS use, size of the divs, amount of actual graphics rendering
>   required per div, target browser/platform, number of DOM event
>   listeners etc..
>
> Just because you can doesn't mean that you should! :-)"

See: [how many div's can you have before the dom slows and becomes unstable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923524/how-many-divs-can-you-have-before-the-dom-slows-and-becomes-unstable?lq=1)

This really is an unanswerable question, with too many factors at too many angles. I will say this however, in a single page load, I used a javascript setinterval at 1ms to continually add new divs to a page with the ID incrementing by 1. My Chrome browser just passed 20,000, and is using 600MB Ram.

Comment: In my previous explorations of this issue browsers seemed to hover at about 3000-4000 dom elements before memory would overload. There has to be a way to benchmark this, I havent found anything obvious yet.

Comment: It really depends on what is IN the DOM Element, I was just adding empty divs. I just closed my browser as it approached a full GB Ram to avoid a crash, it was almost to 40k. I'm also on an vPro I7 CPU.

Comment: Well put. With so many factors, this question is similar to "How fast can a car go".  Although I will say, this line of questioning, tested on different browsers, combined with survey info about reasonable expectations for modern desktop hardware would provide some fruitful results.

Comment: I loaded a table with 1 million TD elements with 4 character strings using framework called 2DX. Browser memory increased by 2.2 GB. With tremor's 600mb per 20 000 it would have add up to 30 GB. The link is http://js2dx.com

Comment: @Gonki you're assuming very much incorrectly, that there is a direct linear mathematical relationship between memory usage and DOM elements.  There is not.

Comment: @tremor, there is a direct relationship while not perfectly linear. Coefficients of the relationship depend on an implementation. According to my tests with one specific browser it is nearly linear in fact. May you elaborate?

Answer (score 6):

For those wondering: Google has it's **Dom size recommendation**:

[Domsize recommandations](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/dom-size#recommendations)

---

"

An optimal DOM tree:

- Has less than 1500 nodes total.
- Has a maximum depth of 32 nodes.
- Has no parent node with more than 60 child nodes.

In general, look for ways to create DOM nodes only when needed, and destroy them when no longer needed.

If your server ships a large DOM tree, try loading your page and manually noting which nodes are displayed. Perhaps you can remove the undisplayed nodes from the loaded document, and only create them after a user gesture, such as a scroll or a button click.

If you create DOM nodes at runtime, Subtree Modification DOM Change Breakpoints can help you pinpoint when nodes get created.

If you can't avoid a large DOM tree, another approach for improving rendering performance is simplifying your CSS selectors. See Reduce The Scope And Complexity Of Style Calculations.

"

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways the DOM elements can become too many. Here is a React + d3 component I have been using to render many elements and get a more real-world sense of the DOM's limits:

```
export const App = React.memo((props) => {
  const gridRef = React.useRef(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (gridRef.current) {
      const table = select(gridRef.current);
      table
        .selectAll("div")
        .data([...new Array(10000)])
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .text(() => "testing");
    }
    if (props.onElementRendered) {
      props.onElementRendered();
    }
  }, []);
  return <div ref={gridRef} />;
});
```

On a 2021 Macbook Pro with 16GB of memory running Chrome I'm seeing serious delay (I think on the paint step) starting at around 30,000 elements

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another data point. I loaded the [single-page GNU Bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html), which claims to be 2064K bytes. In the console, I typed `document.querySelectorAll('*')` and the answer was **22183 nodes**, which rather exceeds Google's alleged "optimal sizes".

I detected no delay loading the page (50Mb ethernet connection). Once loaded, I detected no delay whatsoever clicking on internal links, scrolling, etc.

This was on my relatively massively powered desktop machine. Tried the same thing on my **Galaxy Note 4** (ancient wifi connection, def not 50Mb). This time (no surprise) I had to wait a few seconds (<5) for it to load. After that, clicking on links and scrolling was again about as instantaneous as my eye could see.

I don't doubt that 30,000 nodes of React could spell trouble, nor that I can have **vastly** more than that number of framework-free simple HTML nodes without the slightest problem. The notion that I should worry about more than 1500 nodes sounds pretty crazy to me, but I'm sure YMMV.

Comment: Thank you for a real-world test on desktop and mobile and post 2014.