# Are there limits on the reasonable amount of HTML that browsers can handle before they start to slow down in regards to page rendering?

Tags: django, google-chrome, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am working to troubleshoot an issue with my Django formsets implementation.  After working with a consultant for a couple hours today...we think it might be related to the amount of HTML that gets generated based on the number of records the formset is processing.  Based on 18,000 lines of HTML...the page takes about 15 seconds to load.  The same page with fewer records loads much more quickly.

We've explored the query thing...and have exhaustively looked at performance metrics on the server side and can't seen anything glaringly sticking out that would be contributing to the perceived slow rendering of the page in the browser.

Has anyone else come to this conclusion with their formsets?  If so, what potential alternatives are there to resolving the slow page rendering issue?  Formsets are great...but it would seem that the browsers have trouble rendering the records when they hit a certain amount?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

How many HTML elements can "modern" browsers "handle" at once? Well think  you need to read this post that i found on stack, this might give you a better understanding and answer to your question! Hope it helps ! [How many HTML elements can "modern" browsers "handle" at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611822/how-many-html-elements-can-modern-browsers-handle-at-once)

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this one is.....if you are in development and DEBUG=TRUE....apparently caching for templates is disabled....or something to that effect.  When I ran a fake production mode to test....it was lightning fast.  By fake production mode I mean I set DEBUG to FALSE...and ran in unsecure production mode.  It's local on my machine so for testing purposes it sufficed.  I'm attributing the slowness to that for now until I get into production.    It only took me like 3 weeks to figure this out.