# Can we use a lot of div tags in HTML5

Tags: html

Just wanted to ask a simple question. I've tried searching around but most of the answers are very old.

Is it okay to use a lot of div tags within HTML5? Is it bad practice or anything along those lines? If so, how much is too much?

Hope this makes sense, thanks in advance!

Edit: Like I said above, most of the stuff are old, like very old, as with HTML5, I just wanted to know if things are different or anything. That "duplicate question" was asked 8 years ago

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how many div's can you have before the dom slows and becomes unstable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923524/how-many-divs-can-you-have-before-the-dom-slows-and-becomes-unstable)

Comment: It's irrelevant how many divs you use. What matters is how large the content of your page is in total. Divs are just one element and have no special meaning. Nothing has changed since the question this is a dupe of was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a lot of `<div>` tags within HTML5, but it's better to use the elements provided to you, so it's less confusing. These elements include  `<nav>`, `<header>`, `<footer>`, `<aside>`, `<article>` and more. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) for a full list of HTML5 elements.